# I want register user after like my facebook page?

Tags: facebook, registration

I am working on one web application.
In which i want register user only after liking my facebook page (Ya it's client requirement!!!)
So is there any way to doing this???
I am using PHP 
Thanks a lot.....

Comment: Is it in a framework or a custom script ?

Answer (score -1):

Okay this is how I would do it.. your question is a little unclear, but i assume you want to save people in your database. you dont tell us what language you are using.

So im giving you a start.

1. Subscribe to the like event
2. Run webmethod if asp.net or call method
3. Save user in db

First subscribe should subscribe to this event. This is in the java script file.

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
       //run webmethod if asp.net
    }
);

In codebehind you if you use asp.net

You open the object with all userdetails and put them in the db.